# Converting UnsafeMutableRawPointer to String(utf8) in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

The question is simple How to convert `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` to `String(encoding: utf8)` in swift.

I get some data from socket written in obj c, the model class looks like

```
@interface PTData : NSObject
@property (readonly) dispatch_data_t dispatchData;
@property (readonly) void *data;
@property (readonly) size_t length;
@end
```

The corresponding obj c code for converting data to String

```
PTExampleTextFrame *textFrame = (PTExampleTextFrame*)payload.data;
textFrame->length = ntohl(textFrame->length);
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:textFrame->utf8text length:textFrame->length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here `PTExampleTextFrame` is a `struct`

```
typedef struct _PTExampleTextFrame {
  uint32_t length;
  uint8_t utf8text[0];
} PTExampleTextFrame;
```

But I can't convert the code to swift. But when I tried to convert the code looks like,

```
let data = Data(bytesNoCopy: payload!.data, count: payload.length,deallocator: .none)

let text = String(bytes: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Somehow I got the answer but the text is prefixed with some escape characters.

> `hi` makes `\0\0\0\u{02}jj`
>
> `long text` to `\0\0L\u{1D}long text`

I didn't get the concept of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` and what is the prefixes.

Comment: What is `PTExampleTextFrame`?

Comment: @MartinR Please look now, `PTExampleTextFrame` is a struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *obj c code for converting data to String* is confirmed to work properly, I recommend you to write an Objective-C extension to work with Swift.

Such as:

PTData+Swift.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class PTData;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface PTData (Swift)
@property (readonly) NSString *message;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

PTData+Swift.m

```
#import "PTData.h"
#import "PTData+Swift.h"

@implementation PTData (Swift)

- (NSString *)message {
    PTExampleTextFrame *textFrame = (PTExampleTextFrame*)self.data;
    uint32_t length = ntohl(textFrame->length);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:textFrame->utf8text
                                                 length:length
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return message;
}

@end
```

{YourProject}-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "PTData.h"
#import "PTData+Swift.h"
```

(You may need to modify `#import "PTData.h"` to include actual headers.)

With the above extension, you can simply write in Swift:

```
debugPrint(payload.message)
```

---

Or else, if you dare insist on writing a Swift equivalent of your *obj c code for converting data to String*, your Swift code shown is a little bit too short.

```
extension PTData {
    var textFrameMessage: String {
        let textFrame = self.data.assumingMemoryBound(to: PTExampleTextFrame.self)
        let length = Int(textFrame.pointee.length.bigEndian)
        let utf8text = self.data
            .advanced(by: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size) // <- Sadly enough, `MemoryLayout.offset(of:)` does not work as expected for `utf8text`
            .assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: utf8text, count: length)
        let message = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8)! // <- This may crash, if the message is not encoded in UTF-8
        return message
    }
}

debugPrint(payload.textFrameMessage)
```

---

I have tested above codes with minimum estimated data, but it may be different than the actual data you receive. Please try and tell me if you find something wrong.

Comment: I wonder if it is a bug that `MemoryLayout<PTExampleTextFrame>.offset(of: \PTExampleTextFrame.utftext)` returns 0, and not 4 (as in C). It is always said that “Swift preserves the memory layout of imported C structures” ...

Comment: Btw (extreme nitpicking): The `bigEndian` property returns the big-endian (aka network byte order) representation of an integer, it corresponds to `htonl()`. For the conversion from network byte order to host byte order there is a `UInt32(bigEndian:)` constructor which corresponds to `ntohl()`. – Of course it does not really make a difference because both byte-swapping operations are identical.

Comment: `let utf8text = self.data + MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size ; let bytes = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: utf8text, count: length)` would also work.

Comment: @MartinR, IMO `offset(of:)` in this case is a bug and should work as you described. And thanks for showing alternatives, though I cannot decide which is better as for now.